# Visual c++ CLR how to send windows message?

Tags: .net, winapi, c++-cli

```
private:
    #define WM_SETTEXT                      0x000C

    void doSomethinggToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
    {
         SendMessage(this->Handle, WM_SETTEXT, (wPARAM)"Some Window Title", 0);
    }
```

results in the following errors:

```
error C2065: 'wPARAM' : undeclared identifier
error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'string'
error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

this->Handle <--- (error) no suiteble conversion from System::IntPtr to HWND

Comment: Did you include `<windows.h>`?

Comment: yes, Joey .... in included it.
the function(LRESULT) is shown as i hover with th mouse over it.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol you need is `WPARAM` (all uppercase), not 'wPARAM'.

Also note that `WM_SETTEXT` actually takes the string parameter as the `lParam` value, not `wParam`:

```
SendMessage(this->Handle, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"Some Window Title");
```

Comment: thank you, but ... `error C2065: 'WPARAM' : undeclared identifier`, maybe i'm too sleepy ... but i have been figuring for ages : )